# Saw moving stars in the sky

Tags: star

So I was out with my friends at a bonfire and we decided to sit down and star gaze, my other friend pointed out a star that looked to be moving and we all followed it with our eyes and t was smaller than the other stars and would disappear for a second and then come back but not blinking. And once it went out of view another one would appear again and just go opposite directions in kind of a circular path not a straight one and they were really fast too. This was like by the Big Dipper btw super confused is there like something that moved in our space that does that, a satellite would’ve gone in a non crazy direction right? And not so many of them..

Comment: Hi - this question is, sad to say, a very common one, and not really related to astronomy. Anything you can see moving is either an aircraft or possibly a satellite.

Comment: I'm afraid that further editing won't get your question reopened ***unless*** you can provide really accurate detail on the exact date and time, and your location when you saw it, and specify what direction you were facing and how high above the horizon it was, and how long it lasted; and also explain *what makes you sure it was none of the possibilities listed in the duplicate question*.